# "adb shell settings put global time_zone" doesn't work programatically in Android

Tags: android, timezone, runtime, adb

I want to put global time zone programatically in Android. The ADB way is like this:

```
adb shell settings put global time_zone Europe/Stockholm
```

When I get the time zone it works fine:

```
adb shell settings get global time_zone
```

The problem is when I want to do this in Android Studio:

```
public void setTimeZone(){

    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("settings put global time_zone Europe/Stockholm");

    }catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

There is no error but the time zone is not set.

Any suggestions please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to change it via adb shell? Try this:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setTimeZone("Europe/Stockholm");
```

You will need to add this permission to your Androidmanifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"/>
```

I hope this helps you.

With a rooted phone you can try this:

```
   try {
        Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

        outputStream.writeBytes("settings put global time_zone Europe/Stockholm\n");
        outputStream.flush();

        outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
        outputStream.flush();
        su.waitFor();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: mmmm your solution works for:   "adb shell getprop persist.sys.timezone" but no for: "adb shell settings get global time_zone". Thanks you also.

Comment: Your command only works with a rooted device. Look at the code provided above, works on my Oneplus Two

Comment: Yes. Thank you, babadaba!